# Reset Java Applet on Reload

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I need to quit firefox and restart it in order for the applet to be refreshed... 
its anoying since i'm still programming it an the class files changes... am i missing some codes which makes it unable to refresh the applet and still take the one from the cache???

So I have a .jar applet in my website, a simulation game that spawns army whenever user clicks on the screen... however whenever I refresh the page, the previous army are still there on the screen..
I want it to be refreshed (as if we're just starting to run the application the first time).

Any Suggestions?

I'd really appreciate it

Thank you....

Comment: reloading the page not working??

Answer (score 2):

Each time you build a new Jar applet add a build number to it, eg `applet.jar?build=123` or `build123/applet.jar`. This is good practice for deployment too as it removes all cache concerns and this can probably be simply automated by your build solution eg `Ant`.

In addition it is worth considering using the `separate_jvm` tag, detailed [here](https://jdk6.dev.java.net/plugin2/#SEPARATE_JVM). Available since 1.6 update 10. It will ensure a new JVM each refresh which prevents you worrying about plug-in idiosyncrasies eg out of memory exceptions due to a lot of refreshes.