# Reset Java Applet on page reload

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet

I need to quit firefox and restart it in order for the applet to be refreshed... its anoying since i'm still programming it an the class files changes... am i missing some codes which makes it unable to refresh the applet and still take the one from the cache???

So I have a .jar applet in my website, a simulation game that spawns army whenever user clicks on the screen... however whenever I refresh the page, the previous army are still there on the screen.. I want it to be refreshed (as if we're just starting to run the application the first time).

I already tried pressing CTRL+f5 but the trick doesn't seem to work

I'd basically like to do it automatically using scripts or something, so that it won't require user to manually press some button on the keyboard

Any Suggestions?

I'd really appreciate it

Thank you....

Comment: How is the content of your applet (armies, clicked dots, and so on) stored ?

Comment: Why did you ask basically the same question again? People answered this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410345/reset-java-applet-on-reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to prevent caching?

```
 Pragma:no-cache
 Cache-Control:no-cache
 Expires:-1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are aware of the appletviewer program in the JDK?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cache by Pressing `Strg + Shift + Entf` and then reloading the Page.

Comment: Yes, that may/may not be working, however I'd like to do it automatically without the user having to press any keys in the keyboard... possibly with scripts or something...

thanks

Comment: In english that is Ctrl-Shift-Refresh

Comment: This hotkeys will clear BROWSER cache, but the applet is cached on JAVA VM side.

Answer (score 0):

Some understanding of the Applet lifecycle may help here.

[init()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#init()) is automatically called when the Applet is first loaded.  This event only happens once.  `start()` is always called just after `init()`
[start()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#start%28%29) is automatically called whenever the user loads a page that hosts the applet.
[stop()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#stop()) is automatically called whenever the user leaves a page that hosts the applet.
[destroy()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#destroy()) is automatically called when the applet is removed from memory.  This event only happens once.  `stop()` is always called just before `destroy()`.

As you can tell from the description of the `start()` and `stop()` methods, the applet isn't unloaded as soon as you leave a page.  I'll be honest, I'm not certain exactly *when* it's unloaded.

However, you could put some code in the Applet's `stop()` method that removes any armies that you added, or do some trickery in the `start()` method to reset the game data.