# Force browser to reload applet everytime

Tags: java, javascript, applet, reload, page-refresh

I have depolyed my applet using [deployJava.js](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#appletTagAttributes) and not using  or  tag. So, first of all, [all those questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432659/reset-java-applet-on-page-reload) you might think as duplicate of this questions, are not exactly duplicate.

Currently, when I refresh my page(contain applet) browser tries to reload the older applet which is causing complications like non-responsive applet. I want to force reload applet, from server and not from browser cache, every time I refresh page and that too without any manual work (like closing/reopening browser or manual browser cache delete). Is there a way to achieve it, any attribute or parameter to pass in runApplet(...) (a function in [deployJava.js](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#appletTagAttributes) ), using javascript or HTML?

Comment: Do the applet use static attributes?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: yes it do, but that can be handled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provide a unique url for your applet each time :) like `your.jar?uniquehash` or `your.1.2.3.jar`

Comment: The page, after a time interval, lets say at mid-night, refreshes itself automatically to load any newer version of applet. Thanks for the humor anyway :)

Comment: @Umer Hayat: I think this is a valid answer, just create a new generic link every time you deploy a new applet (e.g. append a release number to the applet's JAR). This approach works for other  resources as well, like CSS, JavaScript.

Comment: Or let your server deliver *.jar resources with a no-cash HTTP header.